# Limiting bootstrap pagination in PHP to 5 pages

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm trying to create pagination in PHP where 5 pages are displayed.

When on the first page we have:

`[1]`[2][3][4][5] ...[325][>>]

Clicking on [325] will take you to that page (the last record), clicking on the right arrow will take you to page [2].

When on the second page we have:
[<<][1]...`[2]`[3][4][5][6] ...[325][>>]

And when on the last page we have:

[<<][1]...[321][322][323][324]`[325]`

I've been researching on how to do this without much luck.  I think I understand that I need to create an array with adjacent pages of 2 on each side of the active page, when we are on any page except the first or last page.  I also need to create an `<li><a href="site_members.php?Page=1">1</a></li>`

and

```
<li><a href="site_members.php?Page=<?php echo $last_record; ?>"><?php echo $last_record; ?></a></li>
```

for when a user is anywhere but the first or last record.

I have the following code which works great, however when we start getting a large number of records, the pagination count gets ridiculous.

```
<ul class="pagination pull-left pagination-md">

     <?php
     // Creates back button in pagination
         if(isset($page)) {

            if($page > 1) {
                $page_minus = $page-1;
            echo "<li><a href='blog.php?page=$page_minus'> &laquo; </a></li>";
            }
         }
     ?>

        <?php 

    global $con;
    $q_pagination = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM admin_panel WHERE ");
    $q_pagination->execute();

    $result_pagination = $q_pagination->get_result();
    $rows_result = $result_pagination->fetch_array();

    $total_rows = array_shift($rows_result);

        $post_per_page = $total_rows/15;
        $post_per_page  = ceil($post_per_page);

    for($i = 1; $i <= $post_per_page; $i++) {
        if(isset($page)){

            if($i == $page) {

                echo "<li class='active'><a href='blog.php?page=$i'>$i</a></li>";
            }
            else { 
                echo "<li><a href='blog.php?page=$i'>$i</a></li>";
            }
        }
    }

    // Creates the forward button in pagination 
        if(isset($page)){

             if($page+1 <= $post_per_page) {
                $page_plus = $page+1;

                echo "<li><a href='blog.php?page=$page_plus'> &raquo; </a></li>";
             } 
         } 
    ?>
     </ul>
```

I'll admit, after researching and attempting to make this work I'm just getting twisted in the logic.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to best approach this?  Leads, current examples, etc.  Most of what I've found is dated, incomplete, or stupid long.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();
```

include "mysqli_connect.php";

```
  $companyID = $_SESSION['compid'];

  $db = new Database();
  $dbc = $db->getConnection();

  $display = 3; //number of records per page
  $pages;

  $dbb = new Database();
  $dbcb = $dbb->getConnection();
   $stat = "select * from reservationStatus where resStatId = '$companyID'  ";

  $r = mysqli_query($dbcb, $stat);

//variable for sorting - default is for registration date
$sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'rd';

switch ($sort) 
{
    case 'ln':
        $orderby = 'uniquenumber ASC';
        break;
    case 'fn':
        $orderby = 'status ASC';
        break;
    case 'rd':
        $orderby = 'resId ASC';
        break;
    case 'em'   :
        $orderby = 'resDate ASC';
        break;
    default:
        $orderby = 'resId ASC';
        break;
}


if(isset($_GET['p']) ) //already calculated
{
    $pages=$_GET['p'];  
}
else
{
    //get the total number of records from the table
    $q = "select count(resId) from reservation where companyID = '$companyID'";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $records=$row[0];

    if($records > $display ) //$display is the number of records per page
    //ceil rounds fractions up to integer value    
      $pages=ceil($records/$display);  
    else
      $pages = 1;
}

//now determine where in the database to start 
if(isset($_GET['s']) ) //already calculated
   $start=$_GET['s'];  
else
    $start = 0;

 //$q = "select * from users LIMIT $start, $display";
 $q = "select * from reservation where companyID = '$companyID' order by $orderby LIMIT $start, $display";

  $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

  if($r)
  {


    echo '<br />';
    //display a table of results
    echo '<div class="container">';
      echo '<h1> Your Orders </h1>';
    echo '<table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="60%">';
    echo '<tr bgcolor="#87CEEB">
          <td><b>View</b></td>
          <td><b>Change Status</b></td>
          <td><b><a href="viewOrdersForCompanies.php?sort=fn"> Reference Number</a></b></td>
          <td><b><a href="viewOrdersForCompanies.php?sort=ln">Status</a></b></td>
          <td><b><a href="viewOrdersForCompanies.php?sort=em">Date</a></b></td>
          <td><b><a href="viewOrdersForCompanies.php?sort=rd">Total Price</a></b></td></tr>';   


//above is the header
//loop below adds the user details    
    //use the following to set alternate backgrounds 
    $bg = '#eeeeee';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
    {

         $stat = "select * from reservationStatus where resStatusId = $row[7] ";

  $rr = mysqli_query($dbcb, $stat);
  $roww = mysqli_fetch_array($rr);

        $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee');

        echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg. '">
            <td><a href="viewTaskForCompany.php?did=' .$row[0]. '">View</a></td>
            <td><a href="changeOrderStatus.php?id=' . $row[0].'">Change Status </a></td>
            <td>'.$row[2].'</td>
            <td>'.$roww[1].'</td>
            <td>'.$row[1]. ' ' . $row[8].'</td>
            <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
              </tr>';
    }
     echo '</table></div>';

  }
  else
  {
      echo '<p class="error">' . $q . '</p>';
      echo '<p class="error"> Oh dear. There was an error</p>';
      echo '<p class="error">' . mysqli_error($dbc) .'</p>';
  }

   mysqli_free_result($r);
      //makes links to other pages if required
    if($pages > 1)
   {
     echo '<br /><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'  ;

     //find out what page we are on
     $currentpage = ($start/$display)+1;

     //need a previous button if not first page
     if($currentpage != 1)
     {
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="viewOrdersForCompanies.php?$s=' . ($start - $display) . 
                '&p=' .$pages . '&sort='.$sort.'">&nbspPrevious&nbsp</a>'; 
     }

     //create the numbered pages
     for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if($i != $currentpage)
         {
             //the 's' paramater is used in the link to determine which the value
             // in the LIMIT clause used in the select statement near the top of the page
             echo '<a href="viewOrdersForCompanies.php?s=' . (($display * ($i-1))) . '&p=' 
                     . $pages . '&sort='.$sort.'">&nbsp' . $i . '&nbsp</a>';
         }
          //&nbsp is a character to insert a whitespace

     }

     //if not last page create next button
     if($currentpage != $pages)
     {
         echo '<a href="viewOrdersForCompanies.php?s=' . ($start+$display) . '&p=' . $pages
                 . '&sort='.$sort.'">&nbspNext&nbsp</a>';
     }

     echo '</p>';

   }


?>
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does, it will improve your answer.

Comment: this is a sample of code that I always use for pagination, there are simple things that you need to change such as 1) the sql statements 2) the page names 3) switch loop change the values. It should work directly it is very easy, if you are still unable to do it please give me your email and I can help you more